# Got wrong answer while solving connected components question using bfs

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

You are given a graph with  n nodes and m edges.
Calculate maximum number of edges that can be removed from the graph so that it contains exactly k connected components.

Input

The first line contains n,m,k(in order).

The next m lines have 2 numbers,ui and vi that showS there is an edge between those nodes.
It is guaranteed that input is valid(no multiple edges and no loops).

Output

Maximum number of edges that can be removed from the graph such that it contains exactly k connected components.
If the graph intially has more  than k  components print -1 .

Here is my solution

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

        int n,m,k;
        cin>>n>>m>>k;
        vector<vector<int>>graph(n+1);
        while(m--)
        {
            int a,b;
            cin>>a>>b;
            graph[a].push_back(b);
            graph[b].push_back(a);
        }

        vector<bool>visited(n+1,false);
        queue<int>q;
        int connected_components=0;
        int span_edges=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(visited[i] == false)
            {
                visited[i]=true;
                q.push(i);
                while(!q.empty())
                {
                    int top=q.front();
                    q.pop();
                    for(auto k : graph[i])
                    {
                       if(!visited[k])
                       {
                           visited[k]=true;
                           span_edges++;
                           q.push(k);
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
            connected_components++;
        }
        if(k<connected_components)
        {
            cout<<-1<<endl;;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<((m-span_edges)+(k-connected_components))<<endl;
        }
    
}
```

I got wring answer however I think the logic is right . I am not much familiar with graphs problems, altough I had read all the graph concepts, can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the input it's hard to be certain, but I would guess that `vector<vector<int>>graph(n);` needs to be `vector<vector<int>>graph(n + 1);` since it seems your nodes are numbered from 1 to n.

Comment: here is the input 4 3 2 
1 2
2 3
1 3 , I made the change as u mention, but now it is giving SIGSEGV error

Comment: here is the link to problem (https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/graph-representation/practice-problems/algorithm/so-np-c559f406/)

Comment: Why do you have `t`, which is not mentioned in the problem statement?

Comment: Sorry man for that mistake I have updated the code however I am getting wrong answer I am not able to figure where I went wrong.. Thanks.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5699329)

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in this line `for(auto k : graph[i])` - you need to iterate over the edges of the vertex stored in the `top` variable, not `i`.